# Spacing around operators on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have tsx files with a following code:

```
i=1;
```

I need to autoformat it like:

```
i = 1;
```

Also I wouldn't mind it for => and for kind of logical operators. Can't find any formatting settings to do this. Can you help me?

Comment: The built-in formatter adds spaces already. Do you have a formatter extension installed?

Comment: Yes, typescript extension. May be it is interfering with the base one. I will check, thanks.

Comment: I have uninstalled all axtensions but the problem persists.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, it was a setting "Format on type". Checked it and all is ok.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work!

Answer (score 0):

adding this to settings.json for VSCode helped me

```
"[javascript]": {
"editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
},
"[javascriptreact]": {
"editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
},
"[typescript]": {
"editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
},
"[typescriptreact]": {
"editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
},
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).